# Android network timeouts on real device, but not on emulator

Tags: android, database, networking, jdbc, android-emulator

Like the title says, I have an android app in which a user logs in via a database query to a remote, functional database via JDBC.  Logging in works on the emulator, and apparently a friend's Nvidia Shield, but not on my Galaxy S4 or my Nexus 7.  I have my internet permission flag set, and the server is acting fine.

My code is as follows:

```
        new Handler().postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    login(email,password);
                    while (user()==null) {}
                    user = user();
                    if (user.equals("")) {
                        failed();
                    } else {
                        success();
                    }
                }
            }, 3000);

public void login (String email, String password) {
    try {
        Connection c = getcon();
        PreparedStatement prep = c.prepareStatement("SELECT user_id FROM [database.table] WHERE Email = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1");
        prep.setString(1, email);
        prep.setString(2, hash(password));
        new login().execute(prep);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class login extends AsyncTask<PreparedStatement, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(PreparedStatement... params) {
        try {
            ResultSet rs = params[0].executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                Log.i("Utilities", "Login Successful");
                return rs.getString(1);
            }
            Log.i("Utilities", "Login Failed!");
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result==null) {
            user = "";
        } else {
            user = result;
        }
    }
}

public Connection getcon() {
    try {
        Connection c = new getconn().execute().get();
        return c;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private class getconn extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Connection> {
    protected Connection doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://dallas113.arvixeshared.com:3306" + "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8","[username]","[password]");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out what could be going wrong?  The error I get is a connection timeout on the line 
`DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://dallas113.arvixeshared.com:3306" + "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8","[username]","[password]");`.  Also, if I am going anything else wrong, let me know, I am new to networking in android.

Comment: What is your target API version?

Comment: @somerandomusername 21.  All devices are at least this.